# fpdf size of text before print

Tags: size, footer, fpdf

Hello I'm using the FPDF and I need help.
I need to print news at the bottom of an invoice, the problem is, I need to know first the size of the news (text) (because people can choose which news will apear in the invoice) and then put the news onto the invoice, but close to the bottom/footer...

My idea is to get the size of the text and save in $theSizeOfNew, then use:

```
//move pointer to the bottom of the page 
$this->SetY(-$theSizeOfNew);
```

and then print the news.

How can I get the size of the news before print?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "a new".
As far as I can understand, your problem is to calculate the size of the string which has to go to the bottom of the page. Right?

There's a method `GetStringWidth(string s)` which gives you the width of the String. This can help you to calculate, if it will be wider than the width of the page and you can find out, how many lines the string will have to take and how often you have to subtract the line height from the y value (bottom of page).

Finally, use `MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])` to add the string.

The manual pages on http://www.fpdf.org/ will give you more information about the methods.

P.S.: I think, the tags "get" and "news" are misleading.